# ERROR: 'Incorrect syntax near ' in declare phrase

Tags: sql

I am stuck with an error

> SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near 'go'

when I declare a variable and execute `select * from @variable`.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

```
declare @vocabulary_database_schema varchar(50)

set @vocabulary_database_schema = 'dbo'

select * from @vocabulary_database_schema.CONCEPT
go
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, there are multiple issues with your code.  Most importantly, you need to use dynamic SQL.  Something like this:

```
declare @vocabulary_database_schema varchar(50);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'select * from @vocabulary_database_schema.CONCEPT';

set @sql = replace(@sql, @vocabulary_database_schema, 'dbo');

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```